# Is there any direct way to cluster points having co-ordinates using DBSCAN algorithm?

Tags: python, dbscan

These are my latitude longitude:

[image]

Can someone help me in clustering these points?
Python code I am using is:

```
dbscan=DBSCAN(eps=.2/6371.,min_samples=2,metric='haversine')
model=dbscan.fit(np.radians(df2))
```

But it's giving only one cluster.

Comment: change eps, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html